# Show first items in foreach - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach

How can i only display the first three items in a foreach in MVC4?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Newstitle)</h4>

    <div class="media">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Newsmessage)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.Take(3)` in your Model. From your code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Take(3)) {
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Newstitle)</h4>

    <div class="media">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Newsmessage)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mate!That works!
i have four news items, but i want to only show the last 3. Now it shows the first 3.

Is that possible too?

Comment: Nevermind! I fix it. ;) 
.OrderBy after it!

Comment: Instead of OrderBy, you can use Model.Last(3).

Answer (score 0):

Your Model is an enumerable, so you can probably do:

```
foreach(var item in Model.Take(3)) ...
```